# Python SELECT with parameters: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: python, azure, pyodbc, sql-server-express

Im trying to find out if an entry is already in the database like so:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id, text FROM dbo.tags WHERE text = ?', str(tag.text))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I am running SQLEXPRESS server.  I have setup the table dbo.tags with a column called text with is of Data Type: text.  I get the following error:

```
  File "scraper.py", line 69, in insertTag
    cursor.execute('SELECT id, text FROM dbo.tags WHERE text = ?', str(tag.text))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

`text` is the column type but I dont undestand why its passing `nvarchar`.  The class property `Tag.text` is just a string.  How can I run this select statement?

I have tried changing the DB Data type to `ntext` but that made no difference.

Please help.

Comment: `text` and `ntext` have been deprecated for many years now. Change your column type to `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL database or on prem?